# Hotmail is not receiving emails from my site and I can't figure out why

Tags: email, phpmailer, hotmail, spf, dkim

If I add the domain to my safe senders list, it works. If not, it doesn't even make it to Junk.

I'm sure I've ticked all the boxes.

- SPF Pass
- DKIM Pass
- No localhosts to be seen
- It's not on any blacklists I can find (domain or IP).

It's sent with PHPMailer.

I am at a loss for what to do next and can't find an appropriate route to contact Microsoft.

Below is the source of an email received on hotmail *with my domain in the safe senders list* (sensitive information replaced/asterisked. "mydomain", "myemail" and "example.com" are all replacements for the real values):

```
x-store-info:qAUQJzZ73IJCLUJ+0n7ZQ106eouhodPhkjqDFiAFSuB4tZQXyiH4g8FNkAhSmURFod13ND6TZMD/gnOqIglAW8tpkW5vrtFUoMWOtYQei71ZMj+mjOsJGx2C4sEW3vt8tRNtdkxvzz8=
Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=pass (sender IP is 104.***.***.***) smtp.mailfrom=robot@example.com; dkim=pass header.d=example.com; x-hmca=pass header.id=robot@example.com
X-SID-PRA: robot@example.com
X-AUTH-Result: PASS
X-SID-Result: PASS
X-Message-Status: n:n
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0wO0Q9MztHRD0zO1NDTD03
X-Message-Info: quWoRize8kCOUP3byGoIEsw7ti1Ho+vM3EsCCpgb6TbPQQZtMXjvE4lEVcSDDgOGbXJhFZkQKpTu+VEWuX+XPzX4PmGNnIcdWj5+3wSYtOiULiJRkeMQBXzIAkPfH5+5O5Ghd3vHFfIFNgpBbao0NpxZW2OMlhrtVadhBGz/OTTtF15wY8BgzY0rLgICPe+Ff6k3qZ3ie6KiZRQZkDwUXQ==
Received: from example.com ([104.***.***.***]) by COL004-MC1F9.hotmail.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(7.5.7601.22712);
Wed, 22 Oct 2014 18:04:22 -0700
Received: from www.example.com (web2.example.com [10.***.***.***])
by example.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 59281120663
for <myemail@hotmail.com>; Wed, 22 Oct 2014 21:04:21 -0400 (EDT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=simple/simple; d=example.com; s=mail;
t=1414026261; bh=m48ADpB+9espPtb1OMTyY0Bj7x43/e+0Xx7q2Ss8yBw=;
h=Date:To:From:Subject:From;
b=qKG2R4w7Ltt+9bo1HVZ34nbHzDnxDOd0d7XnruZvDWFd/kQzKQpRnSSFpKmSs2FK6
XjQdBcJF1+fkK0O4zQxyORP7jow5qOVFTY2PAvXThFzlcoFa4ZLPjZEUee7R03ywCd
XB6yxYT3yZfeiwKaRqI6I2Xixpd2fudrUnOdQxZw=
Date: Wed, 22 Oct 2014 21:04:21 -0400
To: myemail@hotmail.com
From: mydomain Robot <robot@example.com>
Subject: [mydomain] Forgotten Password
Message-ID: <0ae650b7321b6492506a0d4611fdc309@www.example.com>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.8 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
boundary="b1_0ae650b7321b6492506a0d4611fdc309"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Return-Path: robot@example.com
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 23 Oct 2014 01:04:22.0290 (UTC) FILETIME=[47E9AF20:01CFEE5D]

--b1_0ae650b7321b6492506a0d4611fdc309
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

Hi,

We have received a forgotten password request for your account. If you did not make this request, you can ignore and delete this email.
If you did make this request, please follow the link below to reset your password.

https://www.example.com/forgottenpassword?Email=myemail%40hotmail.com&Token=ae97b58a414a

This is an automated message, please do not reply to it.


--b1_0ae650b7321b6492506a0d4611fdc309
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii

<p><img alt="" src="http://www.example.com/design/img/logo.png" style="height:50px; width:228px" /></p>

<p>Hi,</p>

<p>We have received a forgotten password request for your account. If you did not make this request, you can ignore and delete this email.<br />
    If you did make this request, please follow the link below to reset your password.</p>

<p>https://www.example.com/forgottenpassword?Email=myemail%40hotmail.com&Token=ae97b58a414a</p>

<p>This is an automated message, please do not reply to it.</p>



--b1_0ae650b7321b6492506a0d4611fdc309--
```

Comment: What is your problem?  The data on your question shows that you have received your mail at your hotmail account.

Comment: only because it's on my safe senders list. If I take it off, as all new users will have, it doesn't get received

Comment: Do you try to break safety guard of 'safe senders list'?  Have you read support page of 'Outlook.com' at http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/outlook-help?ocid=Outlook_O_MSCOM_Navigation_Support_Support_null?

Comment: I'm not sure what trying to break the safety guard of 'safe senders list' means. I have read the support page and been through the contact us process, but it's all for users of outlook.com, not for this type of problem it seems. I have now posted on the community forum there though.

Answer (score 0):

Must be that tour servers IP is blacklisted. I has the same problema with Gmail I tried sending messages from Cpanel Squirremail and I got nothing in Gmail just because someone sent spam from the server and it got blacklisted. After the hosting provider changed the server IP it worked

Comment: According to http://www.rackaid.com/blog/hotmail-blacklist-removal/ I should get a bounce email in that case and I get none. I've also done a blacklist search (don't remember if it included hotmail.com, but it searched 88 or so blacklists) and it was clean